# Filling the top part of this window?

Tags: html, css

I've got a popup window that looks like this
[image]

Now I want to top part where the color is green and it says "Sök efter ärende" to strech all the way of the window so that the X that is used to close the window is right at the very right. I tried setting colspan to a larger value but that did not work. Do you have any idea what I could do? This is my HTML for the window

```
<div class="popup" id="popupF" 
            style="display: none;" >


<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"
    align="center" class="TB_nb">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="pusher TB_nb"><h2>Sök efter ärende</h2>
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:void(0)"
            onclick="document.getElementById('popupF').style.display = 'none';">X</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<h2 class="pusher">Sök efter ärende</h2>
<div id="FVsok">

    <div
        style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;">
        <span
            onClick="getElementById('FsokF').style.display='', getElementById('FbottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('FbottomV').style.display='', getElementById('FVsok').style.display='none'"
            class="link_sm">Visa s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
    </div>

</div>

<div id="FsokF">

    <div
        style="text-align: right; width: 100%; padding-right: 5%; padding-top: 5px;; padding-bottom: 5px;">
        <span
            onClick="getElementById('FsokF').style.display='none', getElementById('FbottomA').style.display='none', getElementById('FbottomV').style.display='', getElementById('FVsok').style.display=''"
            class="link_sm">D&ouml;lj s&ouml;kformul&auml;r</span>
    </div>

    <div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 80px;"
        class="fontS80">

        <div class="fl30">&nbsp;S&ouml;k efter ärende</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="fl30">
            <input type="text" size="60"
                name="searchArende">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>

        <div class="fl30">
            <input type="button" value="Avbryt">
        </div>
        <div class="fl10">
            <input type="button" value="  S&ouml;k  "
                onclick="javascript:doSubmit('Arendesokning', 'search')">
        </div>
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

</div>
<div style="width: 100%; margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px;">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"
        align="center">
        <tr>
            <td><h3>Sökresultat:</h3>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">En massa text <span class="link">Hj&auml;lp!</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" value="Visa alla">
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="smallb">
            <td>Antal &auml;renden: 0</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Visa &auml;renden: <a class="link"
                href="javascript:doSubmit('MenyNavigation', 'REW_includes/fullfoljd_fran_sok.jsp')">
                     </a> &nbsp;  &nbsp; <a class="link"
                href="javascript:doSubmit('MenyNavigation', 'FWD_includes/fullfoljd_fran_sok.jsp')">
                     </a></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table width="100%" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="sortable"
        id="unique_id">
        <tr>
            <th class="thkant">Ärende</th>
            <th class="thkant">Ingivningsdag</th>
            <th class="thkant">Sökande1</th>
            <th class="thkant">Uppfinnare1</th>
            <th class="thkant">Ombud1</th>
            <!--
    <th class="thkant">Region</th>
    <th class="thkant">Land</th>
    <th class="thkant">Telefonnummer</th>-->
        </tr>



        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


        <tr  class="g2"
            onmouseover="javascript:setStoreStyle(this)"
            ; onmouseout="javascript:getStoreStyle(this)" 
            onclick="javascript:goToOversikt('','','','','','')"
            style="cursor: pointer;">

            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>

        </tr>


    </table>


    <div id="FbottomV">
        <table width="100%" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><input type="button" id="visaknapp"
                    value="Visa" disabled style="width: 150px;"
                    onClick="getElementById('sokR').style.display='', getElementById('bottomA').style.display='', getElementById('bottomV').style.display='none', getElementById('Vsok').style.display='', getElementById('sokF').style.display='none'">
                </td>
                <td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt"
                    style="width: 150px;" class="checkmargin"><input
                    type="button" value="Infoga" disabled style="width: 150px;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="FbottomA" style="display: none">
        <table width="100%" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td align="left"><input type="button"
                    value="&Auml;ndra i register" style="width: 150px;">
                </td>
                <td align="right"><input type="button" value="Avbryt"
                    style="width: 150px;" class="checkmargin"><input
                    type="button" value="Infoga" style="width: 150px;">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

        </div>
```

And this is the CSS

```
*  {font-family:arial;}

.avnamn{ 
                color: #90002b; 
                font-size: 140%; 
                display: inline; 
                vertical-align: 3%; 
                margin-left: 1%;
                }

.b{border:1px solid #000;}

.readonly{background-color: #CCC;}

.Webdings{
    font-family: Webdings;
    }

ul{margin-top: 0px}

.mt3{margin-top:-3px;}
.mt5p{margin-top:5px;}

.fontS80 {font-size: 80%;} 
a:link{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:visited{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:hover{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
a:active{color:#000; text-decoration:none; }

.fontS75 {font-size: 75%;} 

.link{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;}

.link_sm{color: #003366;
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;}

.link_sm{font-size: 70%;cursor: pointer;}

.small{font-size: 75%;}

.smallg{font-size: 75%;
color: #555;}

.ssmall{
    font-size: 65%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #555;
}
.small60{font-size: 60%;}
.small50{
    font-size: 50%;
    color: #333;
}
.smallb{font-size: 85%;}
table{display:inline;}

h1{font-size: 130%;display:inline;}
h2{font-size: 100%;display:inline;}
h3{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
h4{font-size: 70%;display:inline;}
h5{
    font-size: 80%;
    display:inline;
    font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.hthin{
    font-size: 125%;
}

.th {text-align: left;}

td, th{font-size: 75%;
    vertical-align: text-top;}
.td_link{cursor: pointer;}
.td40{height:40px;}
.td60{height:60px;}



.thkant{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 70%;
        text-align: left;
}

.labb{F0F0E3; c1c1b3 }

.bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #000;}
.bbV{border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_nbA {background-color:#CCC;}
.TB_bt, .TB_nb, .TB_db, .TB_bb {background-color:#efefdc;}

.hk {background-color:#d9ddb3;}

.hknot {background-color:#f9faf2;}
/*<!--F8F8F1-->*/
.TB_bt{border-top: 1px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bt5{border-top: 5px solid #FFF;}
.TB_bb{border-bottom: 1px solid #999;}
.TB_bb2{border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;}
.TB_db{border-bottom: 1px solid #000; border-top: 1px solid #000;}
.TB_tb{border-top: 2px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo{border: 2px solid #efefdc;}
.TB_bo_hk{border-top: 1px solid #efefdc;}


.TB_bo2{border: 1px solid #efefdc;}

.TB_bo2B{
border-top: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
border-left: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-right: 3px solid #efefdc;
border-bottom: 2px solid #c1c1b3;
}

.TD_bo{
    border-right: 1px solid #c1c1b3;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.TD_bo2{

    border-right: 0;
    width: 9%;
    font-size: 70%;
    text-align: center;
}

.ytb{
    border-left:3px solid #efefdc;
    border-right:3px solid #efefdc;
}

.datum {
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    vertical-align: text-top;} 
.sub {background:#EAEAEA;}
.sub_meny, .sub_meny_r, .sub_meny_active, .sub_meny_sm{
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;}

.sub_meny_sm {
    font-size: 60%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}   

.sub_meny_r{
    float:right;
    font-size: 70%;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;}

.sub_meny_rm{margin-top:4px;}
.sub_meny_active{font-weight: bold;}

.flikkant1 {
    background-image: url(../images/fl1k.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    z-index: -1;}

.inl_namn{
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 70%;
    color: Black;
    text-decoration: none;}

.th{text-align: left;}
.tr{text-align: right;}

.g1{
    background-color: #FFF;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g2{
    background-color: #EEE;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.g3{
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100%;
}
.g4{
    background-color: #CCC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.popup{
    border-color: #000; 
    border-style: groove; 
    border-width: 2px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-size: 70%;
}

.popuphandlaggare{ 
    border-color: #000;
    border-style: groove;      
    border-width: 2px;      
    padding: 0px;      
    background-color: #FFF;     
    font-size: 70%;     
    position: absolute;     
    top: 900px; 
    }

.popupN{
    background-color: #F0F0E3;
    color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: auto;
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.pin{padding: 6px;}

.fl10, .fl20, .fl30, .fl40, .fl50, .fl60, .fl70, .fl80, .fl90, .fl100 {
    padding-bottom:4px;color: #000000;
}

.over{
    background-color: #EFEFDC;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.half{
line-height:50%;
}

.quarter{
line-height:25%;
}

.lh10{
line-height:10%;
}

.checkmargin {margin-right: 25px;}  
.checkmarginL {margin-left: 25px;}  

.pusher {padding-left: 15px;"}
.pusherR {margin-right: 40px;"}

.rand3{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 3px;}
.rand1{background-color: #FFF; line-height: 1px;}

.whiteborder {     color: #ffffff;      border: 4px solid #ffffff;      padding: 10px;      margin: 10px; }
#details { width: 700; color: #ffffff; }
.column1 {     color: #000000; margin: 0;      padding: 0;     width: 600px;     border:0;     float: left; }
.column2 {     color: #000000;margin: 0;      padding: 0;     border:0;     width: 80px;     float: right; }

.f200 {
    color: #000000;
}

.f210 {
    color: #000000;float: left;
}
.f220 {
    width: 400;
}
.f1450 {
    width: 600;
    float:left;
}
.f1550 {
    width: 150;
    float:left;
    padding:15px;
}
.paddedcell {
    padding:15px;
}
.b2{border:2px solid #efefdc;}
.inp_sel{width: 80%;}

.fl21{float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:150px;} .fl455{float:left; padding:5px; margin:5px; width:120px;} 

.form-bg {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:1000px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.form-bg2 {
  background: #eeefdf;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.data-bar {
  border-bottom:1px solid #fbfbf7;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 10px;
}

.left {
float:left;
width:200px;

}
.discount {
float:right;
width:500px;

}
.discounts {
width:900px;

}
.right {
float:right;
width:700px;
}
.yta20 {
background: #eeefdf;
width:1100px;
}

.yta2 {

width:1100px;
}

.data-box {
width:650px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid #cbcbcb;
}
#table td { 
margin:120px; 
} 

#personName {     float:left;     width:300px;   }  #otherDetails {     float:right;     width:450px;      }

.th_rad_sort {border-bottom: 2px solid #000000; text-decoration: none;"}

a img { border: 0; outline:0;}

.horizontal-gradient2 {
    background: #1a2adb; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%, #a1e6ed 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1a2adb), color-stop(100%,#a1e6ed)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left,  #1a2adb 0%,#a1e6ed 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1a2adb', endColorstr='#a1e6ed',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
    color: white;
    width: 1015px;
}
.f { float: right;     color: white; }


.handlaggare { width: 1000px; }

div.data-box-nat{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
}
div.data-box-pct{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    width: 600px;
}
.newpopup {
z-index:100;
 position: absolute; 
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  background-color:#ffffff; //not working

}
```

Comment: Why oh why are you using a table here?

Comment: @AlexThomas It's legacy code that I inherited. I try to use DIVs instead of tables where appriopriate but this project I'm working on has a lot of tables for layout.

Comment: thats fine, but if it was me, i would invest the time in making the code correct.

Comment: You can just paste the minimal working code, and point to the problem to get quick answers.

Comment: It's working now. I had mixed up positioning elements for the windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the top (troublesome) table to div:

```
<div id="topBar">
  <span class="pusher TB_nb"><h2>Sök efter ärende</h2></span>
  <span id="close">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('popupF').style.display = 'none';">X</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Then add this css:

```
#topBar {width:100%; background-color:#EFEFDC;}
#close {position:absolute; right:5px;}
```

Heres an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FSra3/

**On a side note**, you really should not be using tables. Tables are for tabular data only, not to be used for layout.

Comment: I can't believe this is not working either. How can I have so different version locally when these fiddles work and I use the exact same code to no success. Are my CSS rules being overridden?

Comment: maybe, but i used your css in the fiddle too... Can i see the live code?

Comment: now I've got the faulty code in a fiddle that we can debug:
http://jsfiddle.net/qffh5/6/

Answer (score 1):

Hey now add **some code**  add your **first table** as like this

**replace** this code of your **first table**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"
    align="center" class="TB_nb" style="display:table;">
    <tr>
        <td width="75%" class="pusher TB_nb"><h2>Sök efter ärende</h2>
        </td>
        <td width="25%" style="text-align:right;"><a href="javascript:void(0)"
            onclick="document.getElementById('popupF').style.display = 'none';">X</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/PMrIyGlV)**

Comment: I did that but it is not working for me. I must have some overriding in my CSS or likewise since I see that it is working in the demo. Thank you for the solution which nevertheless didn't work for me since my page is too complex.

Comment: now I've got the faulty code in a fiddle that we can debug:
http://jsfiddle.net/qffh5/6/ where the top of the window is not displaying correctly in internet explorer.

Comment: it's working now. I had mixed up some elements that did the positioning .

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you still want to use table. In css file, you make display style of table as inline `table{display:inline;}` This makes the table shrink to fit its content. Use this instead: `table{display:block;}`

Comment: I put the faulty code in a fiddle that we can debug:
http://jsfiddle.net/qffh5/6/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I got the problem fixed now. It was due to a mixup of `left`and `width` CSS elements.