# Debugging a popup that doesn't display correctly in IE9

Tags: html, css

I've asked this in another question where we could not solve it

[Filling the top part of this window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841793/filling-the-top-part-of-this-window)

and now I've got the faulty code in a fiddle that we can debug:
http://jsfiddle.net/qffh5/6/

In internet explorer 9 the top of the window is not filling all the way. I suspect that CSS is being overridden so I looked in IE with the developer tools but couldn't find what was wrong:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I pinpoint your issue I noticed that the styles are not correctly inherited.
So i have cleaned up your fiddle so that only the "problem" existed.

html

```
<div id="topBar">
    <span class="pusher TB_nb">
        <h2>Some text</h2>
    </span>
    <span id="close">
       <a href="#todo" onclick="#do something">X</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Your CSS

```
#topBar {width:100%; background-color:#EFEFDC;}
#close {position:absolute; right:5px;}
```

****Fiddle with only this part:*** http://jsfiddle.net/qffh5/30/*

Corrected CSS

```
#topBar {width:100%; background-color:#EFEFDC; display:inline-block;}
#topBar h2 {float:left}
#close {position:relative; float:right;}​
```

**fiddle can be  found here : http://jsfiddle.net/qffh5/28/**

Comment: I see it works in a fiddle but when I take the code to my local page which is larger then it is not working. I will try and update the page and this question to see what can be done.

Comment: This is caused because your style sheet is not proper, you have all classes mixed so its very unclear what styles are applied.

Comment: What can be done about it? I have another window that is a popup and it doesn't have this stupid problem. I'm fed up with debugging this, can you propose? I'm just going through and through the same stupid changes and it's not working even though I have several fiddles that we can make that are working, the fiddles are just no the same as taking the code to my larger local page. There really should be a solution and what is it?

Comment: the most easiest and dirty way is to make the classnames more unique: rename topbar to topbarPopup for example and do the same thing in your CSS. Do this also for all other styles that are needed in this topBar section..

Comment: It's working now! I had gotten CSS elements mixed up that were width and should be left. The CSS was deined in another file called positions.css that is used to set the positions on the page for the popups. I'm very happy now that all my bugs are fixed, layout bugs can be the trickiest to have since they are so difficult to debug. But dividing the page into smaller and smaller fractions while keeping the error, seeing that it went away when I removed the other stylesheet, made me realize the problem was in the other stylesheet!